# How can i add a custom javascript module to custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, custom

Hi this code is working perfect without magento.

```
 <script src="flipbook.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$('#side').FlipBook({
        pdf: 'sample.pdf',
       });
</script>
```

i added to flipbook.js to  view/frontend/templates/web/js
and added to layout

```
<script src="test_test::js/flipbook.js"/>
```

phtml

```
<div id="side></div>   
 <script>

require(['jquery'], function($){


    $('#side').FlipBook({
        pdf: 'sample.pdf',
       });


});

</script>
```

Can u explain why its not working?
And how can i fix it?

Comment: Is there any error in browser console?

Comment: yea, Uncaught TypeError: $(...).FlipBook is not a function
    at 17:992
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
    at Module.check (require.js:866)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1143)
    at Module.init (require.js:774)
    at require.js:1416

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<script>
  require(['jquery','FlipBook'], function($){
  $('#side').FlipBook({
     pdf: 'sample.pdf',
    });
   });
</script>
```

For more about the implementation [custom javascript implementation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html)

Hope this helps.